# Is it possible to give harakat when we use an Arabic keyboard layout?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, osx-leopard, arabic

How can I give [harakat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics#Harakat_(short_vowel_marks)) to my Arabic font writing when I use an Arabic keyboard layout?

I'm a [Dvorak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard_layout) touch typist, but I can still type in QWERTY if I really need to do so. Sometimes I need to type Arabic whilst looking at its "Show Keyboard Viewer" because I don't remember the Arabic QWERTY layout yet. I'm not familiar with it, either.

I use Arabic QWERTY, [Pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pages_(word_processor)) and [Mac OS X v10.5.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (Leopard). My MacBook Pro physical keyboard layout is QWERTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option + a letter key should do the trick.

I'm more familiar with the standard Arabic input, but a quick test on my Macbook with the input set to Arabic-QWERTY shows option+w being a shadda, option-u being a Damma, and so on. On the keyboard viewer, clicking its option key will show a new keyset that includes the short vowels.

If your physical keyboard layout is in Dvorak I'm not sure the letters will be exactly the same, but this should give you a starting point.